# Proof of $A = \{x \mid f(x) \leq g(x)\}$ is closed in X

Tags: general-topology

I am facing trouble in the following problems in Munkres:

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $Y$ be an ordered set with its order topology. let $f, g : X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous. Show that the set $A = \{x \mid f(x) \leq g(x)\}$ is closed in X.

I found a solution which is as follows:

The complement of $A$ in $X$ is
$X − A = \{x \mid g(x) < f(x)\}$. We will show that $X − A$ is open. Suppose that $ X − A$ is non-empty and pick an arbitrary element $x_{0} \in X − A$. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be elements in $Y$ such
that $a \leq g(x_0) < b \leq f(x_0) \leq c$. In the order topology, $[a, b)$ and $[b, c]$ are open sets. Because $ f $ and $g$ are continuous, $g^{-1}([a, b))$ and $f^{-1}[b,c)$ are open in $X$. Their intersection is an open neighborhood of $x_0$ which is entirely contained in $ X − A$. Since $x_0 $is an arbitrary element of $X − A$, we conclude that $X − A$ is open.

Link for the solution: http://www.personal.psu.edu/auw4/math429-practice1.pdf

Is this the correct solution?

Because if $b= f(x_0) = c$, then $[b,c] = \{c\}$ is not open in $Y$.

Please advise me.

Comment: Why are $[a, b)$, $[b, c]$ open?

Comment: I think if there exist a smallest element in $Y$, denote it by $a$. then $[a,b)$ is open in $Y$ (in the order topology).

Comment: But the proof is obviously wrong for e.g. $Y = \mathbb R$.

Comment: $[a,b)$ need not be open, but $(a,b)$ is and that is enough. Likewise for $(b, c)$ instead of $(b,c]$. But $b$ inbetween need not exist, as not all order are order dense...If $a$ exists $a$ and $c$ are unnecessary just use subbasic $(\leftarrow, b), (b, \rightarrow)$ instead...

Answer (score 2):

No the solution is not completely correct. You'll have to consider cases.

1. There is no element of $Y$ between $g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)$; then $(\gets,g(x_0)]$ and $[f(x_0),\to)$ are disjoint open sets around $g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)$ respectively and the intersection of their preimages works
2. There is a $b$ between $g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)$; then $(\gets,b)$ and $(b,\to)$ are disjoint open sets around $g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)$ respectively and the intersection of their preimages works.